# Virtual Host Not Behaving Properly

Tags: php, apache, wamp, virtualhost, web-deployment

This problem has been bugging me for days and I really need an answer.
I have a previous WAMP server in which I have configured properly so I can set up virtual hosts for applications that I build. It served me well for months.

Recently, there's this software, in which I think is a Malware, that run in my pc. The software was removed and I scanned the pc and there were no viruses.

I re-installed WAMP server and configured it again. It went well but the virtual hosts are not behaving properly.

These are what I have declared:

In httpd-vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin #removed
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/Thesis"
    ServerName pixtcha.dev
        <Directory "c:/wamp/www/Thesis">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Order Deny,Allow
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin #removed
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/mvc-pe-system/web"
    ServerName copers.com
        <Directory "c:/wamp/www/mvc-pe-system/web">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride all
            Order Deny,Allow
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   pixtcha.dev
127.0.0.1   copers.com
```

1. The thing is, I am able to access the pixtcha.dev properly and there were no problems, while the ***copers.com*** is inaccessible, when I type it, it redirects me to some website from the web. I just don't understand why this happens. I even tried flushing the dns if there were corrupted local files but I just can't figure it out.
2. Also, I have tried using the server names from my previous virtual host and they are all inaccessible too. They are giving me:

   ```
   http://copers.edu.ph is not available
   ```

So I resorted to using new server names, but I don't understand why can't I use the previous server names from my previous WAMP configuration. :(

What do you think are the problems? And how to solve them?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache. Redirects are sometimes cached by the browser.

Comment: copers.com and copers.edu.ph are different things, in case you wonder.

Comment: I just re-installed Chrome and removed the Cache, there's one interesting thing I saw.
Whenever I type copers.com/*something is added here*

Comment: What version of WAMPServer have you installed?

Comment: @Riggs I installed version WAMPServer 2.4

Answer (score 1):

Ok a couple of things that might help here.

As Apache 2.4 is IPV4 and IPV6 aware you need to change your HOSTS file like this so if the browser decides to use IPV6 it knows where to find your domains. I wish I knew what controls the broswers decision, but I dont.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   pixtcha.dev
127.0.0.1   copers.com

::1   localhost
::1   pixtcha.dev
::1   copers.com
```

Dont forget to restart the `dnscache` or reboot after changing this file.
From a command windows, started using the 'Run as Administrator' option, do these 2 commands to restart the `dnscache`.

```
net stop  dnscache
net start dnscache
```

Also when you create Virtual Hosts the default host, as defined in httpd.conf, is ignored, so you need to add a VHOST definition for localhost.

Also you are using old Apache 2.2 syntax in your VHOST definitions, **incorrectly as well as it happens**, and this should be changed to Apache 2.4 syntax

Also it is better to stick to lower case for directory names, Windows does not care but if you ever move code to a Unix live server it may cause confusion.

```
# Should be the first VHOST definition so that it is the default virtual host
# Also access rights should remain restricted to the local PC and the local network
# So that any random ip address attack will recieve an error code and not gain access
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin #removed
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/thesis"
    ServerName pixtcha.dev
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/thesis">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin #removed
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/mvc-pe-system/web"
    ServerName copers.com
    <Directory "c:/wamp/www/mvc-pe-system/web">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'll try doing all that you said and keep note of all those important points. Thanks. :)

Comment: Your solution is working, but with a minor inconsistencies, I cannot access the virtual hosts when I'm not connected to the internet and used hosts from my previous WAMP cannot be reused anymore, it keeps on loading "webpage unavailable". I don't know why.

Comment: It sounds like your system might not load the TCP Stack when you are not connected to a network/internet. Without TPC you cannot use Apache and MySQL. They use it to communicate with each other and the browser uses it to communicate with Apache,

Comment: Do you know any ways to fix that TCP Stack issue? So I can try it in fixing the problem that I have.. Thank you RiggsFolly.

Comment: Sorry no I dont, and I am not absolutely sure thats the issue. It justs seems possible

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure that your scripts (PHP?) in your copers.com root (index.php?) are not redirecting to these outside URLs, or to URLs further inside your local site that would redirect outside as well.

Also in Chrome, you can open the Network tab of Developer Tools to see what actual web requests are being made, and in what order.